# B767 antenna identification

Tags: avionics, boeing

[image: B767 picture with circled feature]

Can anyone identify which comms/nav system the circled antenna belongs to?

Thanks.

Comment: I‘d have to double check, but I believe it’s a drain mast rather than an antenna.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is one of two heated drain masts for the lavatory sinks.

[image]

[How does the drainage of the gray water work?](https://picgra.com/media/1950054083360838113)

[image]